# Are microwave switches universally compatible?

Tags: switch, doors

I want to know if it's possible to other manufacturer's parts in place of LG.  Is there someone I can contact to see if they are interchangeable?

Comment: In [my experience](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/243267/35141) microwave switches are somewhat generic. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Does LG not have them or are they charging a new microwave price for them?  A fast search on amazon seems to agree with @isherwood

Comment: They tend to be pretty common by vintage, but they do change a bit over time.   Also have to check if they are NC vs NO and how many terminals.

Comment: If you post a photo, maybe someone can find one that matches.

Comment: Also, some have 2 and some have 3 wire contacts.